# Tangent to an ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

I want to find the tangent on point $(x_0, y_0)$ to an ellipse with equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

We assume $y_0$ is positive. We can derive $y=\frac b a \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$.

In order to find the slope I use the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac b a \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\sqrt{a^2-x_0^2}}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac b a \frac{a^2-x^2-a^2+x_0^2}{(x-x_0)(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\sqrt{a^2-x_0^2})}
$$
The amount of this limit is obviously zero. Where's the problem?

Comment: It is not zero. You can write $a^2-x^2-a^2+x_0^2=(x_0-x)(x_0+x)$ and then simplify.

Comment: It becomes $x_0^2-x^2$ which converges to zero when $x$ approaches $x_0$.

Comment: The numerator might converge to zero as written, when taken alone, but the denominator does too. Therefore, the limit is not zero but an indeterminate (of the form $0/0$). In order to get rid of this indeterminate, one method is to simplify some common term of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to show that $\frac{xx_0}{a^2}+\frac{yy_0}{b^2}$ is an equation of the tangent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RHS of that equality, the numerator should be $(a^2-x^2)-(a^2-x_0^{\,2})$, which is equal to $-x^2+x_0^{\,2}$. This, in turn, is equal to $-(x-x_0)(x+x_0)$. So, your limit becomes$$-\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac ba\frac{x+x_0}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\sqrt{a^2-x_0^{\,2}}}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.